# Is it possible to create a widget that builds an array of widgets?

Tags: flutter

I have some Widget groups that go into various list based widgets throughout my app, with this kind of structure:

```
bool showB = false

Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      WidgetA(),
      FlatButton(onPressed: () => setState(() => showB = !showB )),
      if(showB) WidgetB(),
    ],
  );
```

I would like to decouple these child widgets from their List/Column view and be able to insert them so that I can decorate the List view with additional things, like:

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ...GroupedWidgets(),
      Text('Something unrelated'),
    ],
  );
```

I initially thought to use a function that returns an array like `List<Widget> groupedWidgets()` but the problem is that I want to encapsulate the state of `showB` for the sake of convenience, otherwise I have to pass `showB` and the function to setState from the outside. So what I really want is a class that acts like a normal widget except that it builds an array of widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own StatefullWidget for the Group like this:

```
class WidgetGroup extends StatefulWidget {
   WidgetGroupState createState() => WidgetGroupState();
}

class WidgetGroupState extends State<WidgetGroup> {
   bool _showB = false;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Column(
         children: <Widget>[
            WidgetA(),
            FlatButton(onPressed: () => setState(() => _showB = !_showB )),
            if (_showB) WidgetB(),
         ],
      );
   }

}
```

Then you could use this Widget anywhere you would need to: in a ListView, Column, Row, basically in any Widget as a child.

In your case you would have something like this:

```
Column(
   children: <Widget>[
      WidgetGroup(),
      Text('Something unrelated'),
   ],
);
```

I hope this solves you problem.

Comment: I should have added that I don't want to nest ScrollViews as that as some implications with ListView.builder

Comment: As long as your WigetGroup is not scrollable this shouldn't make a difference as it is just a regular Widget. If you want to nest Scrollable Widgets you might want to take a look at the [NestedScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html)

Comment: Some of the widgets within the WidgetGroup are scrollable. really should have provided more context with this q! apologies